# Single Grafana chart drawing data from two prometheus instances at the same time

Tags: prometheus

We have multiple prometheus instances. But each of them might be missing some data.

It would be great if there is a way to draw data from multiple prometheus instances on the same chart at the same time so that we can visualize the most complete set of our data.

I have noticed that the Data Source type variable in Grafana allows Multi-value:

[image]

I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. As chart is still drawing data from single prometheus instance among the multiple ones I selected.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print data from different datasource on the same panel in Grafana, then it's not possible natively.
You'll have to create a panel for each datasource.

However, it's possible to achieve this with the use of external tool such as [thanos](https://thanos.io/) or [Cortex](https://cortexmetrics.io/).

Those tools allows you, among other things, to have a single entrypoint that'll aggregate the metrics from all your prometheus instances. This way, you'll be able to print them all in the same panel in Grafana using Thanos or Cortex as the datasource.

However, be aware that adding such tool is no simple task and you'll have to re-think your prometheus architecture. Those tools are not just for aggregating data from different prometheus server. They will also allows you to scale your architecture easily and gives you new possibilities regarding metrics storage.

Comment: Yeah, we have thanos on our to-do list. Meanwhile, I'm wondering how difficult / likely it would be for Grafana to support merging data from two prometheus sources in the same chart.